# PHP Untar-gz without exec()?

Tags: php, exec, tar

How would I untar-gz a file in php without the use of `exec('tar')` or any other commands, using pure PHP?

My problem is as follows; I have a 26mb tar.gz file that needs to be uploaded onto my server and extracted. I have tried using net2ftp to extract it, but it doesn't support tar.gz uncompressing after upload.

I'm using a free web host, so they don't allow any `exec()` commands, and they don't allow access to a prompt. So how would I go about untaring this?

Does PHP have a built in command?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Since PHP 5.3.0 you do not need to use `Archive_Tar`.

There is new class to work on tar archive: [The PharData class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.phardata.php).

To extract an archive (using [`PharData::extractTo()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/phardata.extractto.php) which work like the `ZipArchive::extractTo()`):

```
try {
    $phar = new PharData('myphar.tar');
    $phar->extractTo('/full/path'); // extract all files
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // handle errors
}
```

And if you have a tar.gz archive, just decompress it before extract (using [`PharData::decompress()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/phardata.decompress.php)):

```
// decompress from gz
$p = new PharData('/path/to/my.tar.gz');
$p->decompress(); // creates /path/to/my.tar

// unarchive from the tar
$phar = new PharData('/path/to/my.tar');
$phar->extractTo('/full/path');
```

Comment: For some reason PharData::extractTo doesn't work in PHP 5.4.0 on Windows. Can't figure out why

Comment: I saw [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13870800/569101) but I do not have a Windows with 5.4.0 to test it, sorry.

Comment: It also, contrary to documentation, does not seem to take directories as the second argument.

Comment: Also PharData fails on certain types of tar contents http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189687/phardata-class-fails-when-tar-contents-has-relative-paths

Comment: to anyone still encountering this error . convert it to zip and then extract it. saw the solution here .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843938/phardata-extractto-method-failed-to-extract-tar-gz-on-linux-environment

Comment: Very cool. I used this on a custom Moodle backup / restore script. They switched from .zip to .tar but disguise their backups as an .mbz. A few lines of code changes and it was working perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

PEAR provides the [`Archive_Tar` class](http://pear.php.net/package/Archive_Tar/), which supports both Gzip and BZ2 compressions, provided you have the zlib and bz2 extensions loaded, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a PHP function which can be used without Phar.
It also works with long filenames and was tested with big TAR archives. Compatible with PHP 5 to 8.

Usage:

```
<?php

$ret = tar_extract ("filename.tar", "./path-to-extract/");

if (empty ($ret["errText"])) {
    print ($ret["fileCnt"]." files extracted.");
    print ($ret["log"]);
}
else {
    print ("Error: ".$ret["errText"]);
    print ($ret["log"]);
}

?>
```

TAR archive functions:

```
<?php

function tar_truncate_name (&$str) {
    for ($i=0;$i<strlen ($str);$i++) {
        if (0==ord (substr ($str, $i, 1)))
            break;
    }

    $str = substr ($str, 0, $i);
}

function tar_checksum (&$str, $size) {
    $checksum = 0;
    for ($i=0;$i<$size;$i++) {
        $checksum += ord (substr ($str, $i, 1));
    }
    return $checksum;
}

function tar_read_header ($fh) 
{
    $header = array (
    "name"    => 100,
    "mode"    => 8,
    "uid"     => 8,
    "gid"     => 8,
    "size"    => 12,
    "mtime"   => 12,
    "chksum"  => 8,
    "linkflag"=> 1,
    "linkname"=> 100,
    "magic"   => 8,
    "uname"   => 32,
    "gname"   => 32,
    "devmajor"=> 8,
    "devminor"=> 8,
    "rest"    => 167
    );

    $dataPos = ftell ($fh)+512;
    $stat = fstat($fh);
    $filesize = $stat['size'];
    if ($dataPos>$filesize) {
        return -1;
    }

    $checksum = 0;
    foreach ($header as $key => $len) {    
        $header[$key] = fread ($fh, $len);
        $read = strlen ($header[$key]);
        if ($read<$len) 
            return -1;
        if ($key=="chksum") {
            $empty = "        ";
            $checksum+=tar_checksum ($empty, 8);
        }
        else
            $checksum+=tar_checksum ($header[$key], $len);
    }
    
    tar_truncate_name ($header["chksum"]);
    if (empty ($header["chksum"])) {
        return false; // Last TAR header
    }
    
    // Checksum 
    if ($header["chksum"]!=sprintf ("%06o", $checksum)) {
        return -1;
    }

    // Parse form octal to decimal
    if (sscanf ($header["size"], "%o", $header["size"])!=1)
        return false;

    if (sscanf ($header["mtime"], "%o", $header["mtime"])!=1)
        return false;

    // Truncate names
    tar_truncate_name ($header["name"]);
    tar_truncate_name ($header["linkname"]);
    tar_truncate_name ($header["uname"]);
    tar_truncate_name ($header["gname"]);

    fseek ($fh, $dataPos);

    if ($header["linkflag"]=="L" && $header["name"]=="././@LongLink") {
        // Read long filename       
        $longFilename = fread ($fh, $header["size"]);
        if (strlen ($longFilename)!=$header["size"])
            return -1;

        // Skip 512 Byte block
        $size=(512-($header["size"] % 512));
        fseek ($fh, ftell ($fh)+$size);

        // Now comes the real block
        $header = tar_read_header ($fh);
        if (!is_array ($header)) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            $header["name"]=trim ($longFilename);
        }
    }
    
    // Remove relative paths for security
    $header["name"] = str_replace (["../", "..\\"], ["./", "./"], $header["name"]);
    return $header;
}

function tar_extract ($tarFilename, $dstPath=".", $options=array ()) {

    $ret = array (
        "fileCnt" => 0,
        "dirCnt" => 0,
        "size" => 0,
        "log" => "",
        "errText" => ""
    );

    $fh = fopen ($tarFilename, "r");
    if (!$fh) {
        $ret["errText"] = "Cannot open TAR file: ".$tarFilename;
        $ret["log"].=$ret["errText"]."\r\n";
        return $ret;
    }
    while (!feof ($fh)) {
        $header = tar_read_header ($fh);
        if (!is_array ($header)) {
            if ($header==-1) {
                $ret["errText"] = "TAR header corrupt.";
                $ret["log"].=$ret["errText"]."\r\n";
            }
            break;
        }
        else
        if ($header["linkflag"]==0) {
            $ret["log"].=$header["name"].", ".$header["size"]."\r\n";

            // Read file
            $dstFilename = $dstPath."/".$header["name"];
            $fh2 = fopen ($dstFilename, "w+");
            if (!$fh2) {
                $ret["errText"] = "Cannot create file: ".$dstFilename;
                $ret["log"].=$ret["errText"]."\r\n";
                break;
            }
            else {
                $size = $header["size"];
                $buf = "";
                while ($size>0) {
                    $bufSize = 0xFFFF;
                    if ($size<$bufSize)
                        $bufSize=$size;
                    $buf = fread ($fh, $bufSize);
                    $read = strlen ($buf);
                    if ($read<=0)
                        break;
                    fwrite ($fh2, $buf);
                    $size-=$read;
                }
                fclose ($fh2);

                // Set file time and mode
                touch ($dstFilename, $header["mtime"], $header["mtime"]);
                chmod ($dstFilename, octdec($header["mode"]));
                if ($size>0) {
                    $ret["errText"] = "Filesize incorrect: ".$dstFilename;
                    $ret["log"].=ret["errText"]."\r\n";
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Skip 512 Byte block
            if (($header["size"] % 512)!=0) {
                $rest = 512-($header["size"] % 512);
                fseek ($fh, ftell ($fh)+$rest);
            }
            $ret["fileCnt"]++;
            $ret["size"]+=$header["size"];
        }
        else 
        if ($header["linkflag"]==5) {
            $dstDir = $dstPath."/".$header["name"];
            if (!is_dir ($dstDir) && !mkdir ($dstDir)) {
                $ret["errText"] = "Cannot create directory: ".$dstDir;
                $ret["log"].=$ret["errText"]."\r\n";
                break;
            }

            // Set directory time and mode
            touch ($dstDir, $header["mtime"], $header["mtime"]);
            // chmod ($dstDir, octdec($header["mode"]));
            $ret["dirCnt"]++;
        }
        else {
            // Unknown linkflag
            // Ignore header but skip size
            if ($header["size"]>0) {
                $size = $header["size"];
                // Skip 512 Byte block
                if ($header["size"]<512)
                    $size=512;
                else
                    $size+=(512-($header["size"] % 512));
                fseek ($fh, ftell ($fh)+$size);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose ($fh);
    return $ret;
}

?>
```