# How do I extract a .tar file in pure PHP on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, tar, phar

I have a PHP script that I want to run on Windows. I need to extract a .tar file. How do I extract the tar file. I know of the PharData class and that works on Linux but not on Windows. My script just dies, no error output or anything. This same block of code runs on Linux. I'm using PHP 5.4.0 on Windows

```
$phar_data = new PharData($out_filepath);
$phar_data->extractTo($destination_folder);
```

Is there an alternative pure PHP way to extract a .tar file?

edit: I should say my real intent is to extract a .tar.gz file, but gzopen does the .gz part. Now I need to take care of the .tar part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's too hard. Try something like this: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/945-PHP-Create-tar-gzip-bzip2-zip-extract-tar-gzip-bzip2-.html