# PHP read file name and content in tar.gz

Tags: php, file, tar, gzip

I have three files *1.txt, 2.txt and 3.txt* in a *tar.gz* file named *info.tar.gz*. How to get the file names (1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt) from info.tar.gz by PHP? and how to get the content in the 3 text files?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878792/how-can-i-read-a-tar-gz-file-with-php

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you [PHP Untar-gz without exec()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416508/php-untar-gz-without-exec) ...given you have PHP >= 5.3

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`Phar`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php) extension for PHP which can be used. If you don't have that extension installed (and don't have permissions to install) you can use `shell_exec()`:

```
$files = explode(PHP_EOL, shell_exec('tar -ztvf info.tar.gz'));
var_dump($files);
```

Comment: By this I get the files name, can you please also show get content and files name using Phar? I tried://$tar = new PharData('info.tar.gz');
$tar->decompress();
$files = new \PharData('info.tar');
$files->extractTo('/full/path/');

Comment: I gave you this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878792/how-can-i-read-a-tar-gz-file-with-php ... Should work