# How to untar files using php in a remote server

Tags: php, compression

Is it possible to `untar` a file in a remote server with php, and without using `exec` or passthru`? I normally do this`ssh`with bash, in a`ssh` console, but I wonder if it is possible to do it with php.

So far, I managed to copy the file using an ftp connection, but I can't find the way to use the tar command in the remote server. Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Found [this library](http://pear.php.net/package/Archive_Tar) using [this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=php+tar). In fact, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878792/how-can-i-read-a-tar-gz-file-with-php) looks better.

Comment: Sorry halfer but this answer didn't answer my question.  This post shows how to untar a file if you are in the same server. What i need it is to untar the file from another server

Answer (score 0):

have had a look here ?

[PHP Untar-gz without exec()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416508/php-untar-gz-without-exec)

if i have understood well this could solve your problem :D

Comment: If you believe this is a duplicate question, a comment is generally better `:)`.

Comment: actually i didn't know what to do ^^''' just a comment and then the moderator will mark as duplicated if it's true?

Comment: The link you are referring works only in the same server you running your php script

Comment: @open: do you mean the link on this answer, or on the dup indicated on the question? You can always retrieve a remote file using `file_get_contents` and then do an operation on it locally.