# PharData extractTo method failed to extract .tar.gz on linux environment

Tags: php, mailchimp, php-5.6, phar

I would like to extract .tar.gz file into the particular folder. I have used cURL to download the .tar.gz file from MailChimp batch operation. I have used below code to extract tar file.

```
$phar = new \PharData('upload/test.tar.gz');
  $phar->extractTo('upload/',null, true);
```

It is working on windows environment. But on Linux(Ubuntu), I got below error when to run above code.

```
 Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message 'Extraction from phar "upload/test.tar" failed: Cannot extract ".", internal error'
```

I have already set default apache user and group permission for upload folder.

```
  sudo chown -R www-data:www-data upload/
```

PHP Version: 5.6.24

I have attach sample .tar.gz file: http://www.simbanic.com/_projects/test/05c902076e.tar.gz

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue: trying to extract the .tar.gz file returned from the MailChimp API 3.0 batch operation. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem with MailChimp batch response archive.
Stupid solution, but it works...

```
$p = new PharData($tarGzArchive, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$p->convertToData(Phar::ZIP);

$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($createdZipArchive);
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo($destinationPath);
    $zip->close();
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! With one more step that is: Decompress the tar.gz first then follow the steps mentioned in this solution.

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day :) The only thing I added here is this row:
$createdZipArchive = str_replace('tar.gz', 'zip', $tarGzArchive);